# Passing an Array of Collections as a Parameter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, parameters

On Excel-VBA I have an array of collections (trying to function as a hashlist) that I want to pass into a function.

This is what I originally had.

```
Dim hashArray(200) As New Collection

populateHashArray(hashArray)
```

```
Function populateHashArray(data As Variant)
    data(2).Add "value"
End Function
```

Whenever the code fires off the `data(2).Add "value"` line I get the following error: *Object variable or With block variable not set.*

**First attempted Fix:** I tried to change the function parameters from "As Variant" to "As Collection"

```
Function populateHashArray(data As Collection)
    data(2).Add "value"
End Function
```

This gave me a ByRef mismatch

Would any of you guys know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a side effect of using `New` in your array declaration - you set up an auto-instancing situation which only applies in the calling sub but not in the called function.

To illustrate:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim hashArray(200) As New Collection

    Debug.Print "hashArray(2) = ", TypeName(hashArray(2)) '>> Collection

    populateHashArray hashArray

End Sub

Function populateHashArray(data() As Collection)
    Debug.Print "data(1) in function = ", TypeName(data(1)) '>> Nothing
    Debug.Print "data(2) in function = ", TypeName(data(2)) '>> Collection
End Function
```

Referencing `hashArray(2)` in *Tester* auto-creates a Collection instance at that position in the array, and it's still there in *populateHashArray*.

`hashArray(1)` was not referenced in *Tester*, so `data(1)` is empty (Nothing) in *populateHashArray*.

More on this: [What is the reason for not instantiating an object at the time of declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114684/what-is-the-reason-for-not-instantiating-an-object-at-the-time-of-declaration)

Comment: This gave me the info I needed. Thank you!